# Reasonable RTP stream timeout period

Tags: networking, stream, streaming, rtp

I'm not an expert in networks. So I would like to know what is the maximum reasonable time bewteen receiving two rtp packets upon which if passed the stream would be considered timedout.

Comment: Timeouts in networking usually depend on the network itself and it's latency. For RTP streams, the amount of concurrent sessions against the server gains in importance as it increases (consider an IVR for instance)

Comment: are there any general guidelines on picking the timeout value? or is it totally upto the server hosts?

Comment: The [RFC 3550](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt) recommends timeout "if no RTP or RTCP packet has been received for a small number of RTCP report intervals (5 is RECOMMENDED)". But then again, the Report interval is not specified and it's subject to the network you are using.